# Transform a DataFrame back to integers after np.nan?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame that looks like this (original is a lot longer):

```
    Country        Energy Supply    Energy Supply per Capita    % Renewable
0   Afghanistan    321              10                          78.6693
1   Albania        102              35                          100
2   Algeria        1959             51                          0.55101
3   American Samoa ...              ...                         0.641026
4   Andorra        9                121                         88.6957
5   Angola         642              27                          70.9091
```

I am trying to replace those pesky '...' with a NaN value using np.nan. But I want to change only those specific '...' values because if I apply np.nan to the df then all the integers are changed to float. I am not sure if I am getting this right, please correct me if I am. The reason why I don't want all the numbers in the df to be float is that I will have to multiply integers by large numbers and it comes up as scientific notation. I tried using this:

```
energy = energy.replace('...', np.nan)
```

But as I said, all numbers from df are turned into float.

Comment: Your command should work absolutely fine.

Comment: `np.nan` is a float.  You can have mixed  floats and integers only if the column is object dtype.

Comment: Pandas 0.25+ supports nullable integer dtype: `Int64`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna write back into file as integer, `df.astype({'col1': 'int32'})` may help.

In numpy, you may need to split integer columns and float columns and operate separately. `my_npArray.astype(int)` may help you